# Update TextView outside Activity through Application

Tags: java, android

I have the following three classes:

---

```
public class ApplicationView extends Application {  

    private static Context mContext;
    private static final String    TAG   = "ApplicationView ";  

    public static Context getContext() {
        Log.i(TAG, "getContext: " + mContext); 
        return mContext;
    }

    public static void setContext(Context mmContext) {
        Log.i(TAG, "setContext: " + mmContext);         
        mContext = mmContext;

    }
}
```

---

```
    public class VideoCapture extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
            ApplicationView.setContext(this);   
        }
    }

--------------------------
public class OverlayView extends SurfaceView  implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    public void updateText()
    {       
        Context mcontext = ApplicationView.getContext();
        ((VideoCapture)mcontext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){                      
                        String NewText = "bla bla bla"                         
                        TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
                        txtView.setText(NewText);
                    }
                });
    }  
}
```

---

In my manifest:

- in application:  android:name="xxx.yyy.zzz.ApplicationView"

  ### - in activity: android:name="xxx.yyy.zzz.VideoCapture"

---

It gives me when I call Update Text the following NullPointerException error:

```
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834):    at xx.yyy.zzz.OverlayView$2.run(OverlayView.java:137)
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834):    at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4591)
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834):    at xxx.yyy.zzz.OverlayView.updateText(OverlayView.java:133)
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834):    at xxx.yyy.zzz.OverlayView$1.onPreviewFrame(OverlayView.java:122)
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834):    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:754)
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-17 11:15:27.850: E/AndroidRuntime(15834):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

What I do wrong? 
There is a better way to call updateText in OverlayView ? 
Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's bad practice when any class except Activity class knows about layouts and/or views of this Activity.
My suggestion is to create method which finds and updates TextView in `VideoCapture` activity and performes this operation on UI thread:

```
public void updateText(final String text) {       
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run(){                                               
                        TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
                        txtView.setText(text);
                    }
                });
    }
```

And call it `OverlayView`:

```
Context mcontext = ApplicationView.getContext();
((VideoCapture) mcontext).updateText("bla bla bla");
```

Comment: I'm confused why did you accept another answer. Anyway, welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think `findViewById()` gives null as result because its executed in the context of `OverlayView` but it should be executed in context of `VideoCapture` like this:

```
TextView txtView = (TextView) ((VideoCapture)mcontext)findViewById(R.id.txt_status);
txtView.setText(text);
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, in this way works. I prefer the solution made by iliakplv. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: You're welcome, then please accept his answer as solution with the green check on the left

Comment: Sorry, but even if your answers was good, as I said, I prefer the other one to better fit my needs. Thanks.

Comment: That was clear when you said it the first time, you clicked the wrong answer, look at my comment above.

Comment: Ahhh ok now I see sorry again ;-)